# Smart html page break

Tags: html, css

I make html reports and print them (or PDF) and want to make smart page breaks. I want to avoid that the heading is on one page and the paragraph on the next page. In that case the next page should start with the heading.

I have tried `page-break-after:avoid` but with no success. And I don't understand why. If I try `page-break-after:always` it works. So I guess the avoid functions is not that good. I always use IE8.

Is their any script way to calculate where the page break should be? If their is I can just make a `page-break-after:always` at that place.

Thanks!
/Georg

Answer (score 1):

This class is only a hint. A page break is only avoided if it can be avoided. If it would mean the result would have to be clipped, a page break will be inserted after all.

I don't think it's possible to calculate where the page breaks would be, because it depends on numerous variables, including printer margins and paper size, which are not accessable in CSS nor JavaScript.

Comment: That is what I guessed. I'm creating the html using ASP.NET so maybe I can calculate the height of the content using ASP.NET? I also have images that have html adresses so I also need to know the height of them.I know the paper size and the margins. I also know all fonts and font sizes. Do you think is't possible?

Comment: I think not. You may come very close, but there's always these small differences. Not every renderer renders a font in exactly the same width. A pixel difference in a whole line of text may cause a word to jump to the next line, shifting the entire page. It will be a massive amount of work and you'll never get it right. You'd better ask yourself why it is so important not to have a break at that point. Maybe you can add `page-break-after: auto` in all the pages where a page break would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I used TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org/) to do something similar. It was easy to get the page breaks in the right place though as it was printing tabular data so I could do a row count.

You could try it with a character count but it wouldn't be as accurate.